# Angular ng-mouseup doesn't work on drag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple span that has a ng-mouseup event. It however doesn't work when the text is dragged over even though there is a mouse up eventually! Why doesn't it get triggered in angular `ng-mouseup`? A sample plunker is https://plnkr.co/edit/yWRjW2dZxAHZXEPqsNeA?p=preview

```
<span ng-controller="Ctrl" ng-mouseup="actionme()">
      Settings Div
</span>
```

Is there any other event that needs to be handled?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to create a angular module and add the controller to this module.

```
angular.module('app', []) //module creation
  .controller('Ctrl', Ctrl); //attaching controller to module
```